# How to properly fix clippy::unused_io_amount for std::net::TcpStream::read()?

Tags: rust, tcp, stream

In the [Rust's book final project](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html) the code compile and run as expected with `cargo run`.

However, `clippy` highlights these commented lines with `clippy::unused_io_amount`

```
let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();          // clippy: read amount is not handled
// --snip--
stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap(); // clippy: written amount is not handled
stream.flush().unwrap();
```

The suggest fix is to change `read` to `read_exact` and `write` to `write_all`. However, when running with this changes I get the following error:

`` thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: UnexpectedEof, message: "failed to fill whole buffer" }', src/main.rs:24:36 ``

**How to fix the clippy:: unused_io_amount warning to be able to properly run the rust final project code without any warnings and have it to work as expected?**

P.s. in the [final project listing](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/blob/d82136cbdc91c598ef9997493aa577b1a349565e/listings/ch20-web-server/no-listing-07-final-code/src/main.rs) `write_all` is included but the warning for `read` continues on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `stream.write(...).unwrap()` will return the number of bytes that have been written into the `stream`. Your warning says that this number is not handled. It means that you should write `let bytes_amount = stream.write(...).unwrap();` and then compare `bytes_amount` with `buffer.len()`.
Why? Because in real life can be a situation when not all data from the buffer were written into the stream. You should handle such situations

The same with the `read` function.

Why `read_exact` fails. The `read_exact` function tries to read bytes to fill a WHOLE buffer but can be a situation the stream ends before the buffer gets filled.